# Is there any open api for Android earbuds

Tags: android

I'm a student and wish to develop an Android app connect to the Android earbuds, hoping to exploit their motion sensors for head movement data, so I was wondering if there’s any related APIs to accomplish this.

So far I've searched for brands like Samsung, Huawei, Xiaomi and Sony, these brands have very little support for their TWS earbuds product on their developers' forums and product pages. Only Samsung's Galaxy Buds have an [unofficial management tool](https://github.com/ThePBone/GalaxyBudsClient) that can help me, but I'm still searching for other brands.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to do this using standard Android framework APIs?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's me not familiar with android app development, but I think it's probably more about if these earbuds manufacturers provide access for us to read its earbuds motion sensor data.